# Battery Power supply for Pi-3, LCD and transceiver

Tags: pi-3, wireless, power-supply, battery

I am using a raspberry pi 3 model B (5V/2A), a sainsmart 7" lcd display (12V/2.5A), and a ESP8266 2.4Ghz transceiver (3.3V) for a project.  It needs to be mobile, so what kind of power supply components would I need to run it from batteries?

Answer (score 4):

You need one [12V battery with enough amp-hours to give you a viable lifespan](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26705/will-any-external-battery-power-a-raspberry-pi/41430#41430), one [5V UBEC](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1385) and one [3.3V regulator](https://www.adafruit.com/products/2165) (with a couple of [capacitors](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2195) on its input and output for stability).

- Connect the battery to the display, the UBEC and the regulator.
- Connect the UBEC to the Pi.
- Connect the regulator to the ESP8266.

Comment: just a quick note the 12V battery needs to have enough amp hours for the intended runtime so something like an A23 will not work.

Comment: The numbers have been run a few times here already (e.g. http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/41430/19949). In this particular case of course the other loads have to be taken into consideration too. 30 W for the display is quite a big deal.

Comment: @SteveRobillard You might get just long enough out of an A23 to see some LEDs flicker hopefully before they're cruelly snatched from your grasp. I was thinking something [a little beefier](https://www.cclcomponents.com/rolls-12v-503ah-c100-flooded-deep-cycle-battery) maybe?

Comment: As was I, but the end user may not know what we do. I would likely go for one of those emergency car starter battery packs. When I first saw the portable requirement I was going to ask for a definition of portable.